# jqGrid toolbar filtering doesn't trigger beforeSearch when searchOnEnter is false

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I dynamically generate jqGrid with datatype: 'local' and loadonce: true. I set a toolbar filter like this:

```
$("#" + grid_id).jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
    beforeSearch: function () {
        alert('beforeSearch');
    },
    stringResult: true,
    searchOnEnter: true
});
```

When searchOnEnter = true the beforeSearch event is triggered and the grid gets filtered. If I change searchOnEnter to false then the event is not triggered and the filtering doesn't happen.

This is my fist attempt of filtring on the local data. All other grids that I use have server side filtering and work fine without hitting Enter key on search.

Can anyone point what I should look for?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - it was my own stupidity. Lower in the code I had:

```
$("#" + grid_id).find('input').off('keydown');
```

I removed it and everything started working.